# Is this a bug on parses end or am I doing something wrong?

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform, swift2

In my first view controller I am using this query.

```
 ParseHelper.getCatagories { (objects:[PFObject]?, error:NSError?) -> Void in
    if error == nil {
        for object in objects! {
            if let catagoryObject = objects! as? [PFObject] {
                self.completeObject = catagoryObject
            }
        }
    }

}
```

and then I am passing the object with the prepareForSegue method. After passing the object to the next view controller I am getting the error.

this is my prepareforsegue method

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
  if segue.identifier == "Carousel" {
    if let nvc:CarouselViewController = segue.destinationViewController as! CarouselViewController {
        nvc.complete = completeObject
    }
  }
}
```

in the next view controller I am getting this error 
`Parse can only call -[PFObject init] on subclasses conforming to PFSubclassing`

Comment: So which line raises that error?

Comment: my app crashes when I segue to the next VC

Comment: Are you trying to parse an array of PFObjects or just a single PFObject?  If an array then you don't need the for loop. Can you show your class definition of CarouselViewController?  My guess is you have defined `complete` as something like `PFObject()` instead of `PFObject?`

Comment: In my `CarouselViewController` I am defining complete as `[PFObject]()` .. Should this be `Complete:PFObject?`